# Restringing a pinless guitar

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, strings

[image: this should be a photo]

My little brother bought a charity shop guitar but I’ve never seen this before. It doesn’t have the pins so I’m worried if I take the strings off I won’t get them back on... are there any videos or tips on how to restring it.

Comment: restringing a priceless guitar

Comment: If the strings wrap around the tuners in a fashion similar to a windlass (I can't tell if the second string is steel or black nylon, but it looks like the latter) be sure to use nylon folk guitar strings rather than steel acoustic guitar strings.  Steel strings may exert too much tension on the guitar and destroy it.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to worry about pins. The ball ends of the strings go under the tailpiece and clip there. Loosen off all the strings, and you'll be able to lift up the tailpiece, revealing most likely slots where the strings attach. They may be holes, but it's unlikely. If there are holes - poke the strings through.

I have a similar guitar, a very old Eko. The slots under the tailpiece have broken away, on a couple, so as a temporary solution, I wrapped the string round the tailpiece, and threaded it through its ball end, then over the bridge. Not a perfect solution, but it makes the guitar usable.

Take the strings off one at a time, and for now, replace with the same gauge. Looks like around 010-048" ish. Make sure you wrap the other end of the strings the right way round the posts on the head. They may not even be correct as you got the guitar. The idea is the strings stay as straight as possible from fingerboard, over the nut, onto the post.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to buy ball end strings when you choose to replace the strings. It is a simple job to restring this type of setup. Remove the old string by cutting it at the twelfth fret and removing the string from the trapeze (that's what the type of string holder you have is called). Then remove the other part of the string (the second half) from the tuning post. Now you can feed the new string into the string hole on the trapeze, pull it through until the ball end is seated. Next attach the other end of the string to the tuning post with enough slack to allow three or four windings of string on the tuning post. Wind it up to pitch, making certain the string is properly seated in the string slots in the saddle and the nut. Another option is to take it into the guitar shop and ask the tech to show you what you need to know. Thanks for the question.

Comment: Does the second string look like nylon or steel to you?  To my eye, it looks like it might be black nylon.